# Get Specific data from MapReduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have the following File as input which consists of 10000 lines as follows

```
250788965731,20090906,200937,200909,621,SUNDAY,WEEKEND,ON-NET,MORNING,OUTGOING,VOICE,25078,PAY_AS_YOU_GO_PER_SECOND_PSB,SUCCESSFUL-RELEASEDBYSERVICE,5,0,1,6.25,635-10-104-40163.
```

I had to print the first column if the 18th column is  lesser than 10 and the 9th column is morning. I did the following code. i'm not getting the output. The output file is empty.

```
public static class MyMap extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, DoubleWritable> {


    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String line = value.toString();
        String[] day=line.split(",");
        double day1=Double.parseDouble(day[17]);
        if(day[8]=="MORNING" && day1<10.0)
        {
        context.write(new Text(day[0]),new DoubleWritable(day1));
        }
    }
}
public static class MyReduce extends Reducer<Text, DoubleWritable, Text,DoubleWritable> {

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<DoubleWritable> values, Context context) 
      throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        String no=values.toString();
        double no1=Double.parseDouble(no);
        if(no1>10.0)
        {
        context.write(key,new DoubleWritable(no1) );
        }

    }
}
```

Please tell what I did wrong? Is the flow correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see a few problems.

First, in your `Mapper`, you should use `.equals()` instead of `==` when comparing `String`s. Otherwise you're just comparing references, and the comparison will fail even if the `String` objects content is the same. There is a possibility that it might succeed because of Java String interning, but I would avoid relying too much on that if that was the original intent.

In your `Reducer`, I am not sure what you want to achieve, but there are a few wrong things that I can spot anyway. The input key is an `Iterable<DoubleWritable>`, so you should iterate over it and apply whatever condition you need on each individual value. Here is how I would rewrite your `Reducer`:

```
public static class MyReduce extends Reducer<Text, DoubleWritable, Text,DoubleWritable> {

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<DoubleWritable> values, Context context) 
      throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        for (DoubleWritable val : values) {
             if (val.get() > 10.0) {
                 context.write(key, val);
             }
        }
    }
}
```

But the overall logic doesn't make much sense. If all you want to do is print the first column when the 18th column is less than 10 and the 9th column is `MORNING`, then you could use a `NullWritable` as output key of your mapper, and write column 1 `day[0]` as your output value. You probably don't even need  `Reducer` in this case, which you could tell Hadoop with `job.setNumReduceTasks(0);`.

One thing that got me thinking, if your input is only 10k lines, do you really need a Hadoop job for this? It seems to me a simple shell script (for example with `awk`) would be enough for this small dataset.

Hope that helps !

Comment: Thank you so much ! I get it. I'm just a beginner in hadoop. I'm doing some homework. That is why i just used a file of 10k lines. I got the output i wanted thank you so much !

Comment: @Suresh_Hadoop No problem, glad to be of help :) If that fixes your problem, don't forget to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. I believe this is a mapper only job as your data already has the values you want to check.
2. Your mapper has emitted values with `day1 < 10.0` while your reducer emits only value ie. `day1 > 10.0` hence none of the values would be outputted by your reducers.

So I think your reducer should look like this:

```
String no=values.toString();
double no1=Double.parseDouble(no);
if(no1 < 10.0)
{
context.write(key,new DoubleWritable(no1) );
}
```

I think that should get your desired output.

Comment: Thank you so much ! Now i got the output !